# Do questions about inverters fit here?

Tags: discussion

Electronics.SE got this question: [My inverter keeps flipping between battery/mains slowly at first, then faster. Why?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/17970/my-inverter-keeps-flipping-between-battery-mains-slowly-at-first-then-faster-wh)

Repair of electronics questions are border line tending toward off-topic for us, would it fit on DIY.SE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say off topic.

We don't do consumer electronics here either (though there are a questions about fridges, air conditioners and the like).

However, I'm just one moderator.

Comment: I agree, off topic.

Comment: I agree, off topic.

Comment: I agree, off topic.

Answer (score 2):

What about https://electronics.stackexchange.com/? An inverter would seem to be an electrical engineering question to me.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to say. The question was asked at electronics.se, but we don't take repair questions like that.

Comment: Ok. Sorry, that's what I was trying to ask. I'm not very familiar with the electronics subsite and was just trying to be helpful.

Comment: @KarlKatzke, nothing to be sorry about, the reason we send the other questions we can here is because we do not do consumer electronics support, we focus on design.